# Get latest build with a status in Artifactory

Tags: dependencies, teamcity, artifactory

I have a Generic repository where we store artifacts from various builds. 
Our builds have 3 possible states - `built, staged, release`. Those states are assigned through the REST API `Build Promotion` call.

In build B I need artifacts of the latest **release** build A. 
How do I do that?

The artifacts have structure:

```
Generic:UNIX/somefolder/123/<artifacts-of-build-id-123>
Generic:UNIX/somefolder/123/<artifacts-of-build-id-124>
```

What I have tried:

a) The build is run on TeamCity, so I tried using the TeamCity plugin. There I tried this dependency pattern: `Generic:UNIX/somefolder/**/*.raw@UNIX :: BuildName :: Build#LAST_RELEASE => build-dir/`  -- this did not work. Using `LATEST` instead of `LAST_RELEASE` did work, but resolved the very latest build, regardless of its status.

b) Using the REST API: I made this call:

```
curl -v --fail --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"buildName": "UNIX :: BuildName :: Build", "buildNumber": "LATEST", "buildStatus": "release"}' \
https://artifactory.srv.int.domain.com/artifactory/api/search/buildArtifacts
```

But that returns `400 Bad Request` error. Removing the "buildStatus" from the JSON helps, but then I, again, get the latest version, regardless of its status.

The build artifacts have those properties:
[image]

EDIT: I don't have a Custom Layout set up, but I made one for this case to test it out. Did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Using both the "buildNumber": "LATEST" And "buildStatus": "release" parameters might create a conflict between the constraints.
Usage of the "buildStatus" parameter is allowed only when not specifying the buildNumber param. i.e:

curl -v --fail --request POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"buildName": "UNIX :: BuildName :: Build", "buildStatus": "release"}' \
https://artifactory.srv.int.domain.com/artifactory/api/search/buildArtifacts

Hope this helps,
Itamar